# ToDecimal from string not returning expected result

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion, cultureinfo

I have the following value `48.81`, it comes as a string from the database, I need to convert it to decimal, I'm using:

```
Dim Seconds As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal((Coordinate.Substring(4, 5)), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

I'm receiving `4881D` and I need `48,81`

Any ideas? I thought `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` was going to help me with that

**EDIT**

The coordinate value is `675900.244`.
I'm "spliting" it like this:

```
Dim Degress As Integer = Coordinate.Substring(0, 2),
Dim Minutes As Integer = Coordinate.Substring(2, 2),
Dim Seconds As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal((Coordinate.Substring(4, 5)), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
Dim Position As Enumerations.EnumCoordinatesPosition = Coordinate.Substring(9, 1)
```

**EDIT**

[image: Showing the error]

**EDIT**

[image: Showing the coordinate]

**EDIT**
This is the value of the coordinate in the database

[image: Showing the value of the coordinate in the DB]

Comment: Is the string from the database `"48.81"`, and not actually `"48,81"`?

Comment: Why does a numeric value comes as string from the database? Most dbms can store more than strings ;-)

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @Guffa It comes as `48.81` cause it's stored as a string, not as a decimal

Comment: @TimSchmelter it's a coordinate, and its saved in the database as a string (can't change it) so, I have to split the whole coordinate in degrees, minutes and seconds

Comment: You didn't give us the value of `Coordinate`.

Comment: This returns 48.81M as expected on my machine: Convert.ToDecimal(("48.81"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: The code from post gives the following results on my machine: 67 degrees, 59 minutes, 0.24 seconds. Is this the result you are looking for?

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal("675900.24".Substring(4, 5), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` => 0.24m i.e. it works for me

Comment: @Andrei VB converts implicit String to Integer

Comment: @CodeInChaos see the EDIT please, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Could you show the value of `databaseCoordinate` variable in the same manner?

Comment: @Andrei done, theres the pic of the full value of the `databaseCoordinate`

Comment: Your screenshots shows that `databaseCoordinate` uses `,` and not `.` as decimal separator.

Comment: @CodeInChaos InvariantCulture shouldn't take both cases? Both strings can be save in the DB with `'` and with the `.`, that's why i'm using InvariantCulture, but I can't make it work.

Comment: I also suspect that your code breaks horribly for angles >100deg or even negative angles

Comment: @CodeInChaos the range for my case is only between 00 and 99

Comment: Luis, your assumption about InvariantCulture's handling of '.' and ',' is wrong - please see the answer below for specifics.

Comment: So, it's actually "48,81", as I expected...

Comment: @Guffa yes, but any ideas why the change? it's stored in the database with a dot `.`

Comment: Either they are actually not stored as strings at all, or they are converted from strings when you select them from the table.

Comment: I think it's time to take this to chat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the variable `databaseCoordinate`, which contains comma instead of dot. InvariantCulture uses comma to separate groups of digits and dot as a decimal symbol. To see this execute the following code:

```
//outputs '.'
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
//outputs ',' 
Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator);
```

What you can do about it:

1. Replace comma with dot before parsing - all your code then will work as expected.
2. Specify decimal separator for `Convert.ToDecimal` method like this:

   ```
   decimal Seconds = Convert.ToDecimal((Coordinate.Substring(4, 5)), new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });
   ```
3. Write update script DB for all DB entries with coordinates to use dot as a decimal symbol.

**Example** - this code gives the results you are expecting:

```
string Coordinate = "100948.811"; //Note the dot instead of comma
int Degress = Convert.ToInt32(Coordinate.Substring(0, 2)); //10
int Minutes = Convert.ToInt32(Coordinate.Substring(2, 2)); //9
decimal Seconds = Convert.ToDecimal((Coordinate.Substring(4, 5)), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //48.81
```

Comment: But if the data from database comes with a `,`? Is the only option to change it to a `.`?

Comment: No, actually this is more like a workaround. The proper solution would be to parse data with the same culture that was used when this data was stored. But I assume that you do not know what was that original culture, and suggested a possible workaround.

Comment: DB stores data with dots, and you receive them with commas? Either coordinates are not strings in DB or there is some intermediate conversion going on that you are not aware of. In first case please show us all the relevant code - how do you load values from DB, how do you pass them to the shown method etc. In second case replacing comma with dot seems to be your only option.

Comment: I've been debugging most of the service, and yes, it's stored with a `.` and I'm receiving a `,`. I made a replacement of the original `string` `databaseCoordinate` in the method and it works with the dot... even tho it's still a mistery for me the reason of this dot/comma change... Thanks a lot for all the time and for the answer.

Comment: Personally I would prefer to specify the DecimalSeparator, not making changes to Coordinate string. Convert.ToDecimal((Coordinate.Substring(4, 5)), new NumberFormatInfo { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });

Comment: @OlavNybø, good point, thanks! Added this option to the post.

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem related to the value received from database; and also a problem with your approach.

First, if you expect a decimal value, then store it as a decimal in the database.

And secondly, you are trying to parse a string which shall have at least 9 chars. what you have is only 5 chars.

`(Coordinate.Substring(4, 5))` here you are declaring that you are expecting at least 9 chars; what you have is only 5 chars.